# Display Set<State> using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am getting PropertyNotFoundException while trying to populate select box in JSP using Spring MVC. I (think) I have all implementation correct. Can anyone point out if I missed anything.

Below is my code snippet:

**Spring MVC in JSP**

```
<form:select path="${field.fieldCode}">
    <form:options items="${states.code}" />
</form:select>
```

**Country and State class**

```
Class State {
  private Long id;
  private Country country;
  private String code;
  private String name;
}

Class Country {
  ....
  private Set<State> states;
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Service("domainGeoService")
public class DomainGeoServiceImpl implements DomainGeoService {
  @Override
  public Set<State> getStates() {
    Country usa = (Country)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Country.class, 1L);
    return usa.getStates();
  }
}
```

**Webflow config**

```
<evaluate expression="domainGeoService.getStates()" result="viewScope.states"/>
```

**Exact exception I am getting **

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'code' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing Spring MVC to following solved the issue.

```
<form:select path="${field.fieldCode}" >
    <form:option value="" label="** Select State **"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${states}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="code"></form:options>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance imported the wrong package? 
Did you explicitly imported `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` in favor of `java.utils.Set` or did your IDE pulled a fast one on you under the table?

Comment: Nope .. I am using `java.utils.Set`